# New Player and Returning Player New Card Recommendations

Tags: magic-the-gathering

I'm a new player learning the game with my spouse's old decks from 1994-2001. We plan on just enjoying MTG at home.  We have no plans to play competitively.

I'd like invest in some of the new cards just for fun as a surprise for my husband. I would appreciate any recommendations for what to purchase, the best "bang for the buck" as it were, to thank him for introducing me to the game.

Thank you for any help. I'm really enjoying learning MTG!

Comment: Are you looking for single (and thus relatively powerful and / or fun) cards, or whole products like a deck or something?

Comment: Whole products are what I am looking for, sorry for not clarifying.

Comment: I have personally had fun with playing the commander format, but I have little experience with the actual ready-made decks so can't really help with recommendations. And it's more of a multiplayer format anyways (as in more than two people at a time in a game).

Answer (score 1):

If you want a ready to play deck, than Wizards sells these so called "Planeswalker Decks". These are not competitive, you won't win a tournament with them, but they are quite cheap, include cards from newest expansion and will play well against each other.

You might still find older products called "Duel Decks". These contain two decks, which are designed to be played against each other. Again, these are not competitive decks but are well suited for "kitchen table" Magic. [Goblins vs Merfolk](https://magic.wizards.com/en/products/duel-decks-merfolk-vs-goblins) is one of the latest product in these category.

If you want something more powerful and expensive, then you might still be able to find "Challenger decks". These are build around archetypes found in current Magic tournaments, but since they are designed for the "Standard" format, many cards in them will not be tournament legal since October. [Here](https://magic.wizards.com/en/products/challenger-decks) you can find more information about them.

If you want to try a format designed for casual Magic, then preconstructed Commander decks might suit you. These contain 100 cards and may contain only a single copy of each card except for basic lands. The decks are designed for multiplayer magic, so you might want to try them with friends. Wizards releases them yearly with [Commander 2018](https://magic.wizards.com/en/products/Commander-2018) being the latest.